# Single FET Bus Switch schematic in EAGLE

Tags: digital-logic, switches, atmega, eaglecad, attiny

I've added a SN74CBT1G384DBV into my schematic in Eagle (which I want to use to enable/disable a logic signal line). Once placed into the schematic there only appear to be connection points for VCC and GND and nothing for the A/B and OE pins.

What am I missing? Looking at the board diagram it is complete with all connections present.

Here is the schematic icon as shown in Eagle (as you can see the board package is complete).

[image]

**Background to problem**

I'm guilty here of asking how to do 'X' in a very specific way even though my real problem is finding out how to do 'Y'. If there is a better solution to the problem I'm trying to solve then I'm interested to hear it. My setup looks something like this:

Master talking I2C ---> AtTiny1634 with switching logic ---> Slave listening to I2C

I need for the AtTiny1634 module to be able to enable/disable I2C communication (I'm assuming just enabling/disabling the SDA line is enough, no problem to leave the clock signal passing through) to the slave device.

Comment: I'm confused - do you have a problem with your schematic or do you have a problem understanding how to implement something or maybe both. I think you should restrict this question to one point IMHO

Comment: Hi Andy, I have a problem with the schematic primarily. I just added the last part in case someone wanted to know the full situation or might offer an alternative solution anyway.

Comment: Why don't you post the schematic?

Comment: Leon - I've added the schematic image from Eagle.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. Create your own.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you reckon the symbol in the library is just wrong then?

Comment: It looks completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks - well before I go down that track I'll ask the question I should have probably asked first: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63756/how-to-block-allow-an-i2c-data-signal-to-pass-on-to-another-device

Answer (score 1):

Try running the *invoke* command: [image: icon]

It is possible that the power/ground has been made a separate gate from the main switch block.  Usually  this is done when you have multiple functional blocks within a chip sharing a single power supply (e.g., a dual/quad switch), but perhaps it is the case here also.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sadly attempting that just pops up "Part has only one gate" so I'm guessing that's not the answer!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that IS the problem, but "invoke" may work differently in the library module than the schematic editor. Or the library just has a bug, that's been known to happen.

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a better answer to this, the Invoke command works like a charm. The main culprit is actually the chosen component.

Pick "Single Bus Buffer Gate with 3-State Outputs" instead. You'll get a op-amp like schematic. Use Invoke on this one and a pop-up window will show up that gives you the option to request a PWRN element. Choosing this will make the VCC and GND pins appear.