# How to block/allow an i2c data signal to pass on to another device

Tags: digital-logic, switches, atmega

I have three devices which I'm working on and one of them needs to control i2c communication between the other two.

Each of the devices is based on an AtMega or AtTiny chip. The Controller (based on some external input not known to either the Master or Slave) needs to be able to decide whether or not to pass on the i2c signals to the Slave.

I'm assuming you can just 'block' the data signal (no need to stop the clock signal being passed through) in some way. I've looked at devices like Single Fet Bus Switches but I wonder if that is the best way or not.

The setup looks like: **Master --i2c-> Controller --i2c-> Slave**

Comment: I think you would want to block the *clock* signal instead of the data line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While pulling the clock line low might work for some instances, it highly depends on how the master and the slave are coded. It might result in failed arbitration attempts or freezing due to unexpected clock stretching.

There are two simple options. One, would be to connect the slave's Clock Line, through a transistor, as you would a simple level translating setup. But instead of connecting the transistor to always on, on a different voltage, the base will be connected to your controller's enable pin. If on, the SCL line is connected to the slave, allowing it to see the Clock Pulses. If off, the slave doesn't see any pulsing on the clock line, so sits idle, and the master doesn't see anything different on the line.

The other options are an i2c buffer, bus expander, or switch, with an enable pin. Some of those tend to require an extra i2c address byte to allow communication to the other side.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation Passerby. This looks ideal for what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off blocking the clock signal.
If you let the slave see the clock but not the data, it will still try to read bits from the data line each time the clock pulses. If you block the clock, the slave won't try reading the bus at all.

One simple, but somewhat crude, method would be to use an open collector output to pull the clock line low, and hold it. As long as the clock line is held low, no communications will be able to take place on the bus. Since you only have 2 devices communicating on the bus anyway, this should be sufficient.

If you had more than 2 devices and you wanted to isolate one of them, while still allowing the others to use the bus, then the bus switches you mentioned would be a better solution.

Comment: Very good point about blocking the clock signal - makes sense when you put it like that! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Pulling the clock low will (should) cause the master to either fail arbitration, or freeze in a clock stretching mode, if configured and coded to i2c spec.

Comment: I did say it was crude. :) If the original poster is using built-in hardware i2c he should check the processor data sheets to make sure this won't break in an unpredictable way. If he's using a software-based i2c stack, check the source code to find out in what way it will break.